# Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting the following error when running
./gradlew assembleDebug

Here is the project
https://github.com/tsynik/LeanbackLauncher

2 Files where the problem needs to be solved
https://github.com/tsynik/LeanbackLauncher/blob/kotlinx/app/src/main/java/com/amazon/tv/leanbacklauncher/MainActivity.kt#L788
https://github.com/tsynik/LeanbackLauncher/blob/kotlinx/app/src/main/java/com/amazon/tv/leanbacklauncher/wallpaper/WallpaperInstaller.kt

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> e: /home/mo123/Templates/LeanbackLauncher/app/src/main/java/com/amazon/tv/leanbacklauncher/MainActivity.kt: (788, 45): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type WallpaperInstaller?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Fix the code to use a safe call (`?.`)` as noted in the error message. See [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html).

Comment: Is this the correct way to add 2 ? WallpaperInstaller?.getInstance(this)?.installWallpaperIfNeeded()

Comment: I suspect that you would only need one, after `getInstance()`: `WallpaperInstaller.getInstance(this)?.installWallpaperIfNeeded()`.